# Quotient ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I think that if $A$ is any commutative ring with unity and $q\in A$, $p\in A[x]$ then we have $A[x]/(q,p)\cong A/(q)[x]/(\bar{p})$ where $\bar{p}$ denotes the class of $p$ in $A/(q)[x]$. Is this true?

Also is there some isomorphism for $A[x]/(q,p)$ with $q\in A[x]$?

Answer (score 10):

You can easily construct an isomorphism using the universal properties of quotient and polynomial rings.

Start as follows: We have $A \to A/q \to A/q [x] \to A/q[x]/(p)$ and the element $x$ in $A/q[x]/(p)$. Hence, we get $A[x] \to A/q[x]/(p)$. Clearly $q$ and $p$ lie in the kernel, so that we get $A[x]/(p,q) \to A/q[x]/(p)$.

Now construct the inverse morphism.

(As always, there is also a one-line proof using representable functors.)

Comment: Note: When we have an inverse morphism (also constructed via the universal properties), there is no need to do fiddly element calculations. Remember that an isomorphism is *by definition* an invertible morphism.

Answer (score 7):

To complement Martin's answer in accordance with the wishes expressed in the comments of the OP, why is the kernel of the canonical map $A[x]/(q,p)\to (A/q)[x]/(\bar{p})$ zero? Suppose $f=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\in A[x]$ is in the kernel. This means that if we reduce the coefficients modulo $(q)$, to get $\bar{f}=\bar{a}_nx^n+\cdots+\bar{a}_1x+\bar{a}_0$, then in $(A/q)[x]$, $\bar{p}$ divides $\bar{f}$. That is, $\bar{f}=\bar{g}\bar{p}$ for some $\bar{g}\in A[x]$ (and we can assume, as the notation suggests, that $\bar{g}$ is the image in $(A/q)[x]$ of a polynomial $g\in A[x]$). Then the image of $f-qp\in A[x]$ in $(A/q)[x]$ is zero. That means that every coefficient of the polynomial $f-gp$ lies in $qA$, i.e., is divisible by $q$. The set of polynomials in $A[x]$ all of whose coefficients are divisible by $q$ is exactly the ideal $qA[x]$, the ideal of $A[x]$ generated by $q$ (verify this if it's not clear to you). So we have $f-gp\in qA[x]$. Thus $f=gp+qh$ for some $h\in A[x]$, and $f\in(q,p)$, the ideal of $A[x]$  generated by $q$ and $p$. This proves the desired injectivity.

As for the second question, regarding the case when $q,p\in A[x]$ but $q$ is not necessarily in $A$, there is nothing that can be said in general. It's just $A[x]/(q,p)$. What would you expect this ring to be isomorphic to other than itself?